# Change R interface to English

Tags: r

I'm having an annoying issue with R. When I start the R console, all the Interface is in Japanese, and I don't know why.

I searched and tried a lot of "solutions" but nothing seems to work. Here I attached a screenshot of how it looks.

[image: ScreenShot of R in MacOS High Sierra]

Comment: Put `Sys.setenv("LANGUAGE"="EN")` in your Rprofile.site file?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your `R_HOME\etc\Rconsole` file contains any config other than en (english) on this line `language = xx`

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the solutions you gave me and posted on other sites, and I realized the problem wasn't the R configuration, it was something on the MacOS preferences. I can't understand why, but if there is a second language in the preferred languages on the Language & Region Settings, R takes that as the interface language.

So, I removed the Japanese as a second language on my Mac, and it solved the problem. I attach a screenshot, maybe it will be helpful for another person that have the same issue as me.

[image: Language & Region Settings]